# Restlets 2.1-RC1- sample performant ClientResource code needed

Tags: java, web-services, http, restlet, restlet-2.0

We are trying to develop/tune a restlet client that will HTTP POST up to 10+ requests per second.

[The restlet website](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/27-restlet/328-restlet/285-restlet.html) gives sample client code for consuming resources. Their example is

```
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource(
            "http://localhost:8182/rest/test");
    TestResource testResource = clientResource.wrap(TestResource.class);

    // Retrieve the JSON value
    Customer result = testResource.retrieve();
```

However [other discussions](http://restlet-discuss.1400322.n2.nabble.com/response-release-versus-response-exhaust-in-2-0-tt5427308.html#none) (and comments on that wiki) say there is a problem with this approach.

It seems unclear if `release()` and/or `exhaust()` should be called to free up resources. I have tried e.g.

```
  ClientResource cs = new ClientResource(rootConnectionString);
  final Representation rep = cs.post(s);
    if (rep != null) {
        final long numBytes = rep.exhaust();
        rep.release();
    }
```

Our client application can not rely on a garbage collector to avoid running out of resources. Ideally we would re-use the same connection / socket to improve performance.

The reason I ask is that our app is not working well under performance tests, we see intermittent problems. I THINK these are client-side as load test with other tools towards the server are ok.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:260)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer.readLine(LoggingSessionInputBuffer.java:115)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:98)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:252)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:247)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:298)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:333)
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:111)
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:109)
at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:190)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1064)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleOutbound(ClientResource.java:1153)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:996)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:972)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.post(ClientResource.java:1381)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.post(ClientResource.java:1327)
```

What would really help is some sample code that cleans up correctly.
Regards,
Kieran